# Command to get the public IP address of a router

Tags: networking, vpn, ip

I have two 18.04.2 Ubuntu computers on my home network behind the same router.

On each computer, if I run this command:

```
curl -4 ifconfig.me
```

I get the same result on each machine, the dynamic public IPv4 IP address currently assigned to the router:  XX.XX.XX.XX.

Then, on computer #1, I start a VPN.  When I then run the same curl command, I get a different result, the IP address that the VPN assigns:  YY.YY.YY.YY.

Question:  What terminal command do I run on computer #1 while the VPN is active on computer #1 to find out the currently assigned dynamic public IPv4 IP address the router is using for computer #2 (which is not using the VPN)?

Comment: Why do you want to find the public IP of computer #2? All together this smells like a [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could ask the router.

If it supports UPnP, then you can use `upnpc` from the **miniupnpc** package

Try:

```
upnpc -s
```

or

```
upnpc -m enp1s0 -s
```

to specify explicitly the *interface* to use. So change `enp1s0` to fit your setup. Obviously, don't use the `tun0` interface or the interface used by the *VPN*, if any.

Comment: solsTiCe :  That second command you suggested is exactly what I needed, thanks, you are the man!  One followup question:  Is there an option for the upnpc command that would also show the IPv6 address as well?

Comment: Please mark the anwer as the accepted solution by ticking the mark on the left. Thanks. With ipv6, you don't do NAT most of the time, so you only deal with the ipv6 of your pc. Nonetheless, have you tried to look at the man page of upnpc ? it says to use something like `-6`, no ?

Comment: No, the man page for upnpc doesn't say anything about IPv6, or an option of "-6".  Well, I didn't see anything like that when I issued this command:  man upnpc .  Hence my followup question.

Comment: Indeed, it is only mentionned in the man page in 19.04. your version might not support `-6` option.

Comment: I can only do this if I use an interface with bridged mode in my VM. It doesn't work when the VM with NAT interfaces (NAT created by the host machine). Is there any way to do this with a router that we are indirectly connected to?

Answer (score 1):

> Question: What terminal command do I run on computer #1 while the VPN is active on computer #1 to find out the currently assigned dynamic public IPv4 IP address the router is using for computer #2 (which is not using the VPN)?

The general answer is that you can't. And with more complex configuration you're not guaranteed that the public IP will belong to your closest router ([Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), multiple routers in private IP space, proxy servers and so forth).

You can add a route for `ifconfig.me`. This is somewhat complex, as the domain points to at least four IP's, and being hosted in Google Cloud, I wouldn't bet on those IP's to be entirely static either.

Nor do you, in more complex configurations, have any assurance that two different computers will exit from the same public IP.

All together this smells like a [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to find the public IP of computer #2?

Comment: It all comes down to laziness.  The two computers are in different places, I spend 90+% of my time on computer #1.  I have a conky script on computer #1 that I set up to show a lot of info including internal and external IP addresses.  Sometimes I need to turn off the VPN on computer #1.  But, I would like to know before I do that what external public IP address my router is using.  Since computer #2 never has a VPN running, I thought that it could tell me that - but I didn't want to get up from my chair and walk over to computer #2.  Instead, I'd like to see that in my conky script

Comment: @dln949 You should add this into your question. Furthermore, do you own the router?

Comment: Yes, I own the router.